# Creating TOC widget for RTL languages in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents, internationalization

I'm trying to make the TOC widget to run from right to left in ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

Is it possible to achieve, and how?

Answer (score 1):

In the container that has the legend, set the attribute dir to rtl. Like this

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_dir.asp

Comment: Thanks for your response but this destroy the tree shape of the toc